# Running Concourse CI on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, concourse

Is there any ways to deploy Concourse (both worker and web parts) via Kubernetes? I faced an issue with docker push:

```
cb1e3aeea39c: Waiting
5dd685fa9d71: Waiting
8a88c6d1419d: Mounted from wodby/php
b37b676c40b5: Mounted from wodby/php
af413e3ea009: Mounted from wodby/php
d142daee8ef2: Mounted from wodby/php
5dd685fa9d71: Mounted from wodby/php
94a8fa70651c: Mounted from wodby/php
cb1e3aeea39c: Mounted from wodby/php
e6ceb8011e49: Mounted from wodby/php
4e86b94d038f: Mounted from wodby/php
dca58c4a8ccb: Mounted from wodby/php
998dedad47e8: Mounted from wodby/php
2bd72896c2d4: Mounted from wodby/php
aa71ffb881e9: Mounted from wodby/php
7cbcbac42c44: Mounted from wodby/php
received unexpected HTTP status: 504 Gateway Time-out
```

So I wonder is it bug or limitation?

Related Github issues:

- https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/936
- https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource/issues/102

Comment: Hi - could you elaborate a bit more on how you did the setup? Which pods/deployments/services you've defined and what you're doing to run into your specific issues?

Comment: If you are running helm in your cluster, there is a chart for deploying concourse to kubernetes:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse

Comment: I am going to guess this has something to do with the s3 outage today...

Comment: I don't use helm, but I created the same k8s manifests manually. Everything works Ok if Concourse Worker running in Docker container but on a host machine, not under k8s.

Comment: I am running it on google container engine. Your question is a bit hard to understand, though. Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Copying coffeepac's answer (Helm) to this question here as it is probably the most canonical response particularly for somebody who can't get it working otherwise, and it is super light-weight:

> If you are running helm in your cluster, there is a chart for
>   deploying concourse to kubernetes:
>   [github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse)

This chart is in the stable repository. Potentially volatile charts are in incubator.

Comment: If you've not come up with the answer yourself, you may want to add it as a community answer instead. Furthermore, could you turn the github link into an actual link? This is done as `[text](<link>)`.

Comment: @N.Wouda Thanks for your feedback! It's not clear to me how to make it a Community Wiki answer instead. It doesn't look like the tickbox exist anymore.